# SQL/PHP Insert not working

Tags: php, sql

This was all working fine a few days ago but now it isn't writing the data to the database anymore and I can't figure out why.

I tried to see if it was an error with getting the data from the CSV file but when I try and upload the data it is successfully echoed back, so it's not that part of the code.

The connection is fine as it's not throwing the 'database connection error'. I have other parts of the system that still work OK with this connection.

I think it is something to do with the table itself in the database rather than the PHP code though. When the INSERT stopped working I tried creating a new identical table and writing to that instead but that didnt work either.

PHP:

```
<?php  

//connect to the database 
$server = 'xx';
$connectionInfo = array(xx);
$connection = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo);

if (!$connection) 
    {
    die('Database connection error');
    }

session_start();

if (isset($_FILES['csv']['size']) == 0) 
{ 

echo "<p2>". "Hello, ". $_SESSION['name'].  ". You can upload your CSV file for your school, ". $_SESSION['school']. ", below."."</p2>";
$school = $_SESSION['school'];
}

if (isset($_FILES['csv']['size']) > 0) { 
    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if (isset($data[0]))
         {                                                          
            $school = $_SESSION['school'];
            $species = $data[0];
            $count = $data[1];      
            $surveyor = $_SESSION['name'];
            date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
            $upload_date = date('d/m/y h:i:s a', time());

            echo "<p2>". $school. " ". $species. " ". $count. " ". $surveyor. " ". $upload_date. "<br>". "</p2>";

            $parameters = array($school, $species, $count, $surveyor, $upload_date);                                                
            $Query = "INSERT INTO findings(School, Species, Count, Surveyor, Upload_Date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
            $results = sqlsrv_query($connection, $Query, $parameters); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
echo "<p2>". "Upload complete". "</p2>". "<br>";
} 

?> 

<body> 

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
   <br /> 
  <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" accept=".csv" /> 
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[findings]
(
    [School] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Species] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Count] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Surveyor] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Upload_Date] DATETIME NOT NULL 
)
```

This is my first time posting on here so please do let me know if you need any further infomation

Comment: Well, take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can read what the issue is, most likely.

Comment: Also some basic error checking and handling would do nicely...

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepare the SQL query before you can run it multiple times, your code appears to be executing the query multiple times as it is in a do while loop..

Some of your params need to be passed by reference ex. $species, &count

```
// Set up the proc params array - be sure to pass the param by reference
$parameters = array($school,
&$species,
&$count, ..., ..., ...
);
```

Do something like this outside your do while...

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $connection, $Query, $parameters);
if( !$stmt ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Inside the loop ...

re asign referenced vars

```
       $species = $data[0];
        $count = $data[1]; 

if(!sqlsrv_execute( $stmt )) {
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd try checking if `sqlsrv_errors()` returns anything after your insert query, something like:

```
$results = sqlsrv_query($connection, $Query, $parameters); 
var_dump(sqlsrv_errors());
```

That might contain your answer.

Answer (score -1):

post what echo this line:

```
echo "<p2>". $school. " ". $species. " ". $count. " ". $surveyor. " ". $upload_date. "<br>". "</p2>";
```

Your table are specified to columns `NOT NULL`. All of variables must have value.

PS: Sorry for my English.