# Submit an array of multiple dropdown options

Tags: php, form-submit

I want to submit all selected options to Sql Server table. But i am having difficulty inserting all selected values. Only the last selected item gets inserted into table. Items in dropdown list is pulled from database table. Multiple options can be selected in dropdown.

How the ouput in table should look like:

[image]

```
<html> 
    <body> 
        <form id="processForm" action="Untitled-2.php" method = 'post'>  
        <h4>SELECT SUBJECTS</h4> 

        <select id="ProcessStatus" name = 'ProcessStatus[]' 
 form="processForm" multiple size = 6>   
                <option disabled selected value>--Please Select Process 
 Status--</option>
                <?php 
                   // Fetch Mine Names
                    $sql = "SELECT ID,ProcessStatus FROM Table1;";
                    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
                    if (!result) {
                        echo "<option disabled>Failed loading Process 
Statuses</option>"; 
                    } else {
                        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result) ){
                            echo "<option value='".$row['ProcessStatus']."'>" 
. $row['ProcessStatus'] . "</option>";
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </select> 
            <input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = Submit> 

        </form> 
    </body> 
</html> 
    <?php 

    // Check if form is submitted successfully 
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  
     { 
        // Check if any option is selected 
        if(isset($_POST["ProcessStatus"]))  
        { 
            // Retrieving each selected option 
            foreach ($_POST['ProcessStatus'] as $subject)  
                print "You selected $subject<br/>"; 
        } 
    else
        echo "Select an option first !!"; 
    } 
?>
```

Untitled-2.php for submiting form:

```
if( isset( $_POST['ProcessStatus'] ) )
{
    $qty = $_POST ['ProcessStatus'] ;
    if( is_array( $qty ) )
    {
        foreach ( $qty as $key => $value ) 
        {
            print( $value." " );
        }
    }
}
    $params = array(&$value);

    # Statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test ([ProcessStatus]) VALUES (?);";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $params);
    if ($stmt === false) {
        echo "Error (sqlsrv_prepare): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        $stmtError = true;
        throw new Exception('SQL statement error');
    }
```

Comment: You are replacing `$value` each time your `foreach` loop iterates.  So you will only ever end up with the final one

Comment: Your INSERT query needs to be executed _inside_ the loop, if you want to insert one of those values at a time.

Comment: pro tip: `echo "<option value='".$row['ProcessStatus']."'>" 
. $row['ProcessStatus'] . "</option>";` is more simply written as `echo "<option>{$row['ProcessStatus']}</option>";`  the value attribute is an unnecessary redundance.

Comment: This looks helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36065329/2943403